# What are the accepted abbreviations for Million Years and Billion Years?

Tags: time, conventions, units, si-units, metrology

I'm putting together some charts and the time axis in one shows billions of years, the time axis in another shows millions of years.  I've seen in various publications $my$ and $myr$ (also $ma$) for millions of years (ago).  I've also seen $Gy$, $Ga$, $Gyr$ and $bya$ for billions of years.

I tried digging up an SI unit reference but didn't have any luck.  Is there any accepted version of abbreviating large units of years that is consistent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the field. There is an ISO standard to use **a** from latin annus, but in astronomy and cosmology **yr** is far more normal. I think the same is true in geology and paleontology. The metric symbols should be capitals, **M** not **m** (which stands for milli-, $1/1000$). **b** is deprecated for billions, use **G**. **ya** is often used for years ago. I use **Myr**, **Mya**, **Gyr**, and **Gya**, which are well accepted and unambiguous. They are also immediately intelligible to people who don't read ISO standards and don't speak latin.

Answer (score 1):

It's Ma for million years and Ga for billion years.